# Cannot change date/time on virtualized centos install without a reboot

Tags: centos, xen, time

I have a dedicated web server which is running centos with xen virtualization that has centos installed on the vm. I do not have access to the parent server, I can only manipulate the vm, of which I have full control. I am having nothing but problems manipulating the date/time on the vm. The main problem now is that the time on my server is running just a little faster than "normal". I would estimate that for every 24 hours it is ahead by an extra minute. This is not good because I have scripts that need to be run at specific times and they are running minutes behind what they should. The only "fix" I have found so far is to reboot the server, but I don't want to reboot every night just to fix the time!

Here is what I have tried:

1) Setting the time manually:

```
root@host [~]# date
Mon May 13 06:52:22 WAKT 2013
root@host [~]# date 051306492013
Mon May 13 06:49:00 WAKT 2013
root@host [~]# date
Mon May 13 06:52:54 WAKT 2013
```

The date and time is reflected on the screen after the set command, but then when I run the date command a second later, it goes back to what the date "actually is". If I reboot the server, the time will be reset properly, but I am trying to avoid this reboot.

2) I was reading about setting the hardware clock which might help me, but I am unable to make any changes or do anything with it, and I believe it is because I am on a vm:

```
root@host [~]# /sbin/hwclock --show
Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.
root@host [~]# hwclock --systohc
Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

3) I enabled ntp, which I believe is working, but like setting the time manually, the time change doesn't "stick" until after a reboot:

```
root@host [~]# date
Mon May 13 06:55:36 WAKT 2013
root@host [~]# service ntpd stop
Shutting down ntpd:                                        [  OK  ]
root@host [~]# ntpdate pool.ntp.org
13 May 06:55:52 ntpdate[7146]: step time server 192.95.20.208 offset -229.150633 sec
root@host [~]# service ntpd start
Starting ntpd:                                             [  OK  ]
root@host [~]# date
Mon May 13 06:56:10 WAKT 2013
```

Also note that I am using some weird timezone for the moment because I was trying to troubleshoot another issue I was having with the timezone being reset: https://serverfault.com/questions/494635/timezone-changing-by-itself-on-virtualized-centos-install so don't focus too much on the timezone. I just need the time to be correct for whatever timezone I am in.

Has anyone dealt with this before? I refuse to believe that there is no way to set the time on my linux box without a reboot. Any ideas or suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: What [clocksource](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen/Clocksource) is your kernel using and what others have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a running a paravirtualized xen vm you can check;

/proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock

If it exists and contains 0 ,
try ( as root ):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independant_wallclock
```

Then launch your ntp server.

Comment: Thank you so much Olivier! This was exactly what my problem was, and although I feel stupid for not finding this myself, I am very glad it was a simple fix! I used instructions from http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/4.0.1/guest/ch04s06.html to persist changes across reboots using the /etc/sysctl.conf file and now ntp is working great!

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, you have to edit your sysctl.conf to make the changes persistent